# Ubuntu - Error on installing xonsh

Tags: python, ubuntu

My ubuntu is 15.04, I using `$ pip install xonsh` and I've installed python-ply but this error still coming

```
Downloading/unpacking xonsh
  Downloading xonsh-0.2.3.tar.gz (135kB): 135kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-A_8MA8/xonsh/setup.py) egg_info for package xonsh
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-A_8MA8/xonsh/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
    ImportError: cannot import name TemporaryDirectory
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-A_8MA8/xonsh/setup.py", line 8, in <module>

    from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

ImportError: cannot import name TemporaryDirectory

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-A_8MA8/xonsh
Storing debug log for failure in /home/altiano/.pip/pip.log
```

What is this? How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xonsh` does not support Python 2 (yet).
I got `classifiers=['Programming Language :: Python :: 3']` from `setup.py`.

To install it you need Python3.

run this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install xonsh
```

Comment: I already got python3 because it comes with ubuntu 15.04

Comment: `python3:
Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 26 2015, 22:03:40) `

Comment: Download xonsh, extract and run `python3 setup.py install` inside extracted directory.

Comment: `ImportError: No module named 'ply'`
I don't get it, I think I've installed it

Comment: anyway this `sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install xonsh` solve my problem,, thanks man..
but what actually is `python3-pip` and why `pip3` instead of `pip`?

Comment: `python3-pip` is used to install  `pip3`.`pip` for python2 and `pip3` for python3.